# Get values from json file in string with separators

Tags: json, api, powershell, github

I have a json file with following format:

```
{
"total_count":  57,
"incomplete_results":  false,
"items":  [
              {
                  "id":  123456,
                  "node_id":  "dfghdfjfgjftgjhtfyjh",
                  "name":  "Firstrepo",
                  "full_name":  "MyOrganization/Firstrepo",
[SKIP]
              },
              {
                  "id":  4756758,
                  "node_id":  "dtghtfjgjyuj",
                  "name":  "Secondrepo",
                  "full_name":  "MyOrganization/Secondrepo",
[SKIP]
              },
              {
                  "id":  568578567,
                  "node_id":  "dsgdfghftghtfyjtyj",
                  "name":  "Anotherrepo",
                  "full_name":  "MyOrganization/Anotherrepo",
[SKIP]
              },
              {
                  "id":  58567856,
                  "node_id":  "sjdhfbgsdjfgjsdfjjs",
                  "name":  "Somerepo",
                  "full_name":  "MyOrganization/Somerepo",
[SKIP]
              },
```

How can I get values of repositories and write them in variable or file in csv format. Like:

```
Firstrepo,Secondrepo,Anotherrepo,Somerepo
```

Script to get values:
CONFIG Get-list of repos from Github

```
$GithubAPIURL = "https://api.github.com"
$Suffix = "/search/repositories"
$Additions = "?q=org:MYORG:SEARCH&page=1&per_page=100" 
$GithubAPIToken = "&access_token=MYTOKEN"
```

PROCESS

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$variable = ((Invoke-Webrequest $GithubAPIURL$Suffix$Additions$GithubAPIToken).content | ConvertFrom-Json)
$jsonfile = "c:\a\test.json"
$variable | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8
```

Get-List of names

```
$Reponames = (Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

Comment: `(Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items.name`

Comment: Awesome! Is there any way to convert list to csv format?

Comment: You don't have to edit your question everytime, you learn something new, this makes an answer kind of obsolete ;)

Comment: @Paxz I think, you're right! Sorry for this. I will undo my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Names of the Repository use:

```
(Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items.name
```

To convert it to a .csv file:

```
(Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $csvFilePath
```

Comment: First command returns me right values, but second - converts in wrong data. I used your second code (some addition): 

(Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items.name | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $csvFile
But it returns wrong data - http://prntscr.com/k8czxl

Comment: First command returns this data (correct but not in csv) - http://prntscr.com/k8d11u  Second - http://prntscr.com/k8czxl - wrong

Comment: I think, It counts letters, for some reason 0_o

Comment: Try `$output = (Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation` and take a look at the variable. If still the same, post the output of `(Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items`

Comment: Well, command     (Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json).items   gets all json info - http://prntscr.com/k8da8h - I cannot post more due to sensitive info

Comment: @VasiliyVegas Then I don't know why it doesn't convert it correct into csv. I tried it with the json example you offered in the question and it worked as expected.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help. Perhaps, this is a problem in formats. I will try to find workaround.